# Create new empty userdata from pure Lua

Tags: lua, lua-userdata

I think I saw somewhere a native function in Lua that can return a new userdata. Does it exist? Is it possible to create custom userdata from normal Lua script?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may be thinking of `newproxy`

From: http://lua-users.org/wiki/HiddenFeatures

> `newproxy` is an unsupported and undocumented function in the Lua base
>   library. From Lua code, the `setmetatable` function may only be used
>   on objects of table type. The `newproxy` function circumvents that
>   limitation by creating a zero-size userdata and setting either a new,
>   empty metatable on it or using the metatable of another `newproxy`
>   instance. We are then free to modify the metatable from Lua. This is
>   the only way to create a proxy object from Lua which honors certain
>   metamethods, such as `__len`.

It was also useful for `__gc` metamethods, as a hack to get a callback when the `newproxy` instance becomes free.

This feature was present in Lua 5.1, but removed in 5.2. In Lua 5.2, `__gc` metamethods can be set on zero sized tables, so the main impetus for `newproxy` went away.

Answer (score 2):

Actually no, in pure Lua.

> The type userdata is provided to allow arbitrary C data to be stored in Lua variables. … Userdata values **cannot be created or modified** in Lua, only through the C API. This guarantees the integrity of data owned by the host program.

[link](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.1)

If you embed luaVM in host C/C++ application, you can export some function to create userdata to Lua, but it's not a good practice. UD is designed to be a blackbox for Lua scripts.