# What is newproxy and how is it useful?

Tags: lua, metatable

I was messing around with Lua yesterday and stumbled upon the 'newproxy' function.

http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Function_dump/Basic_functions#newproxy

I kind of understand it, but I'm not sure how it is useful. I know it creates a blank userdata object with a metatable attached (if the argument is true).

How it newproxy useful? Here is an example of what I did while messing around with it:

```
local proxy = newproxy(true)
local metatable = getmetatable(proxy)

metatable.__index = function(array, key) print(array, key) end

local y = proxy[100]

--[[
    OUTPUT:
        userdata: 0x443ad4b4 100
]]
```

Comment: http://lua-users.org/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?action=browse&id=HiddenFeatures&revision=15

Comment: Slightly more lightweight than a table, and supports some meta-methods not supported on tables before it was removed again.

Comment: `newproxy` was deprecated in Lua 5.1 and removed in Lua 5.2.

Answer (score 1):

See [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23592388/create-new-empty-userdata-from-pure-lua) and answer. Empty userdata were useful for detecting when GC reclaimed objects. That role can be played by zero sized tables in Lua 5.2.