# Why was Lua's newproxy deprecated and removed?

Tags: lua, lua-5.1

So in 5.1 of Lua, `newproxy` was deprecated. In 5.2, it got removed. But why? What should I use now to construct a userdata?

I'm trying to implement pseudo-classes for fun and userdatas are way easier. They make implementing immutability and restricting writing to certain keys much easier.

Comment: You can't create userdata from Lua script.  Use tables and their metatables.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Lua tables are...fat. An empty table takes around 40 bytes. It also makes immutability harder to implement. Since `__newindex` is *always* invoked on non-tables, that makes it easier for me. Unless there is another way. Proxy tables are still too much work.

Comment: An empty table takes 72 bytes.  newproxy [is not needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23593617/1847592) in Lua 5.2+

Comment: "*They make implementing immutability and restricting writing to certain keys much easier.*" How? If you implement the `index` and `newindex` metamethods, you can do the same thing with an empty table as you can do with a userdata. And you *have* to implement those on a userdata if you want to give them "members". So what's the difference, besides the function you use to create them?

Comment: You always can create simple C module with this function

Answer (score 3):

You probably shouldn't have been using `newproxy` like that at all, I am not sure it was even doing what you thought it was doing.

The `newproxy` function was undocumented, it was likely removed because it was made redundant by documented features in 5.2.

> **8.1.6 newproxy removed.**
>
> This was always an 'undocumented' function in Lua 5.1, and it was considered unnecessary, since it was chiefly used to write finalizers. Since the `__gc` metamethod now works for Lua tables, this workaround is no longer needed. -
>   [What Lua 5.1 code breaks in Lua 5.2](http://underpop.online.fr/l/lua/faq/8-1-what-lua-5-1-code-breaks-in-lua-5-2.html#8.1.6)

You also wont find anything in the [Lua 5.2 Manual - Section 8 Incompatibilities with the Previous Version](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#8) regarding `newproxy` as it was undocumented.

Answer (score 3):

In 5.1, there were some inconsistencies between the metatable functionality of a userdata and a table (the `#` operator didn't call `__len` in 5.1 when used on a table). 5.2 removed those inconsistencies, so there is no difference between a table's metatable and a userdata's metatable.

As such, there is no need for it. It is very easy to write a near-exact equivalent to `newproxy`, with the only difference being the type of the object returned:

```
function newproxy(new_meta)
    local proxy = {}

    if(new_meta == true) then
        local mt = {}
        setmetatable(proxy, mt)
    elseif(new_meta == false)
    else
        --new_meta must have a metatable.
        local mt = getmetatable(new_meta)
        setmetatable(proxy, mt)
    end

    return proxy
end
```

Of course, since you're writing a new function anyway, you could also give it an improved API. Such as a way to create proxies with a given metatable, rather than giving it a table/userdata that has a metatable.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: It would have taken less time to edit it than to write a comment.

Comment: Yes.  But a comment would let you memorize that Lua is not Python ;-)